# What does "up" mean in "up the pitch?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain what "up" means in this sentence? Does it mean "on"? So "up the pitch" means "on the pitch".

> 26 mins – Ireland get short at the back as they lose the ball while Doherty is **up the pitch**, but Omobamidele nips over to that right channel and snuffs out the danger.

> Players move the ball **up the pitch** and attempt to score goals.

Comment: What do you suppose it could mean?  I think, from context, there is only one possible way to understand "up".  Take a look at some of the other ways in which "up" can b.e used

Comment: @JamesK I take it to mean "on the pitch".

Comment: See Michael's answer.

Comment: @KateBunting - now withdrawn.

Comment: _I'm confused whether "up" refers to the opposing pitch in this pitch?_ I'm no rugby expert, but both teams are playing on the _same_ pitch! For each team 'up' is the direction in which they need to send the ball in order to score.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting, but would add the observation (which is therefore curious) that in American football one talks of a team’s moving the ball **down** the field toward the goal line. So in that case, *down* means forward, in the desired direction.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I would like to understand your use of "would" in your sentence. Does it mean "will"? "I **will** add the observation that in American football ...

Comment: This is, of course, a new question. I suggest you search “would vs. will,” and if you don’t find an answer there, you (1) post the question **and** (2) be sure to explain what it is about your question that hasn’t been addressed in any previous posts and answers. That’s how one is supposed to use ELL.

Comment: @KateBunting This is about football (soccer). It's still unclear. Does **up** mean towards in this context?

Comment: What is the aim of soccer? The object of the game is to move the ball **up the pitch** and beyond the goal line of your opponent's goal. (Bundesliga)

Comment: Sorry - I was confused by the rugby references in Michael's (now deleted) answer. Isn't your second example clear? **Up** means **in the direction of the opponent's goal**. It doesn't mean 'towards' - 'towards the pitch' doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KateBunting - OP seems unclear about the meaning of 'pitch'.

Answer (score 2):

'Up' can be used as an adverb, a preposition and an adjective. In your text it is a preposition meaning 'along' or 'further along' (e.g. a road, path, sports pitch). In soccer, for a player or team, the 'up' direction is towards the opposing team's goal, and 'down' is the other way.

up preposition (ALONG)

> A2 (further) along:
> *The car shot off up the road at high speed.*
> *They live just up the road.*

[Up (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up)

> What is the aim of soccer? The object of the game is to move the ball
> **up the pitch** and beyond the goal line of your opponent's goal.

[All You need to know about soccer (Bundesliga.com)](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/faq/all-you-need-to-know-about-soccer)

Comment: Does "up" mean *along* as well? Player move the ball **up the pitch** and attempt to score goals.

Comment: @Nyambek - I already wrote that in my answer.

Comment: Can we substitute "up" for "on" here?

Comment: I'm confused whether "up" refers to the opposing pitch in this pitch? Up the pitch = along the opposing pitch.